# What is the shape of trajectory followed by a particle whose velocity is given by $\vec v = (u_0 + bx) \hat i - (by) \hat j$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(Here $u_0$ and $b$ are positive constants and $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ are perpendicular unit vectors in X and Y direction in rectangular Cartesian coordinate system respectively.)

So this question recently came on my test and my teacher and I got very different answers.

Let me show you both of our methods

My approach :

We can say that at every instant for particle x changes as  $${dx \over dt} = u_0 + bx \tag{1}$$ and $${dy\over dt} = -by \tag{2}$$

So $${dy \over dx} = {-by \over u_0 + bx} \tag{3}$$

So solving this differential equation (which I skip here) we get $$ y = { k \over b(u_0 + bx)} \tag{4}$$ Where k is a arbitrary constant

My teachers approach :

Same as above except he took 
$${dy\over dt} = by \tag{5}$$ (not $-by$)

And so got $${dy \over dx} = {by \over u_0 + bx} \tag{6}$$ Solving which yields $$y = x + c \tag{7}$$ here c is a arbitrary constant.

This got me thinking all that we did different was a negative sign and that resulted in completely different trajectories.

*What I expected a negative sign to do was just flip the axis (reverse the direction of velocity vector in y direction) so to give trajectories symmetric about X axis.*

My question: **Why do we get these radically different answers? And which one of us is correct?**

(It would really help if you *can* explain this visually or intuitively)

Comment: I think your confusion is coming from the fact you've only flipped the sign in one component, not both. That's bound to have a large impact on the result.

Comment: This  is a question about mathematics rather than physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil If you think this is a mathematics question you may migrate it to mathematics stackexchange. I do not mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minus sign actually makes a big difference since you are working with differential equations. What your teacher used can be imagined by an exponential growth in x and y, and both values are growing with the
 same rate b, so what you get is a straight line with the slope 1.

Whereas you used a minus sign which implies that the y value is decreasing exponentially in time while the x value is increasing. Which parameterizes a different and obviously more complicated trajectory.

I did not calculate the whole thing but if you did no mistake with your calculations you should be right if the minus sign you wrote in the title was also printed in your exercise.

I hope this helped. :)